# FrameTooLongException Mime HTTP Header size calculation

Tags: http, netty, mime

When receiving a response back with a netty client object, I run into a FrameTooLongException.  After taking a tcpdump, found that the response received is a large Mutlipart Mime response with about 200 parts (each with some short headers), but the actual HTTP Header for the response is quite small and are listed as;

```
> Host: foobar.com:20804
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
< Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 19:44:09 GMT
< Vary: Accept
< Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="63602357878446117"
< Content-Length: 33023
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this, but are Mime part headers used in the HTTP Header size calculation, and does Netty parse it as such?

The exception I get is as follows:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes.
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.newException(HttpObjectDecoder.java:787)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.process(HttpObjectDecoder.java:779)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.forEachByteAsc0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1022)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.forEachByte(AbstractByteBuf.java:1000)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.parse(HttpObjectDecoder.java:751)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.readHeaders(HttpObjectDecoder.java:545)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:221)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:136)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:315)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:229)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:147)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1044)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:934)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:315)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:229)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:847)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
```

Comment: Could you post an example of header up to body part ?

Comment: @FredericBrégier Edited question with header info

Answer (score 1):

Http header terminates with 2 cr/lf (such as between Accept and HTTP in your example), and header shall start with a "start line" (HTTP/1.1...).

Therefore I see 2 issues with your example:

1. Your header does not start correctly : HTTP/1.1 should be the first line, followed later on by your accept and other host header params.
2. Probably there is something wrong in your response such that there is no 2 cr/of between your header and the body, thus leading to the decoding of the body as if it was part of the header, so the exception...

Comment: So I copied the above headers from the curl output.  HTTP/1.1 is the first line (denoted by the < sign, I'll edit).

Looking at the tcpdump as per your second point, I do see two line endings.

Comment: If you have a reproducer, might be interesting to submit it as an issue in netty at github?